# Angular ng-switch inside select option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-switch

I want the [Data Presentation Format] applied to [Dropdown Box]. I need the "parent" to be presented as is inside the dropdown box, but I need the "child" to be presented with with a [tab], to show the parent-child relationship.

$scope.itemlist will be prepared in order (i.e. parenta, childa1, childa2, parentb, childb1, childb2)

The HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<h1>-- Data Presentation Format --</h1>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in itemlist">
        <div ng-switch on="item[1]">
            <div ng-switch-when="Parent">{{item[0]}}</div>
            <div ng-switch-default>&emsp;{{item[0]}}</div>
        </div>    
    </li>
</ul> 
<br/>
<h1>-- Dropdown Box --</h1>
<select ng-model="loc1" ng-options="item[0] for item in itemlist">
    <option value="">Item</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<h1>-- What I Got --</h1>
<select ng-model="loc2">
    <option ng-repeat="item in itemlist">
        <div ng-switch on="item[1]">
            <div ng-switch-when="Parent">{{item[0]}}</div>
            <div ng-switch-default>&emsp;{{item[0]}}</div>
        </div>    
    </option>
</select>
```

The javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.itemlist =
    [
    ["Unit A", "Parent"], 
    ["Room A", "Child"], 
    ["Room B", "Child"], 
    ["Room C", "Child"], 
    ["Room D", "Child"], 
    ["Room E", "Child"], 
    ["Unit 1", "Parent"],
    ["Room 1", "Child"], 
    ["Room 2", "Child"], 
    ["Room 3", "Child"]
    ];
}
```

JsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11174/

Comment: divs inside option invalid html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use   inside the option element, as its not rendered as html. If you insist on using the  element instead of something like a jQuery dropdown (which basically is a ), then i'd suggest using dashes or similar to illustrate parent/child relationship.

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11177/

I solved it using a formatting function i placed on the scope

```
$scope.formattedItem = function(item) {
    return item[1] === 'Parent' ? item[0] : '--' + item[0];


<select ng-model="loc2">
    <option ng-repeat="item in itemlist" >
        {{formattedItem(item)}}
    </option>
</select>
```